# How to disable enter key in JQGrid Edit?

Tags: jqgrid

I've using JQgrid, and using inline edit all working fine but i need to disable the enter key press. Means if user entering values and click enter it not need to do any action. Now its trying to store the data as per edit url. But i don't need this functionality.

Just Disable enter key press on JQGrid.
Can any one help?

Hi Oleg As u asked i'm pasting my code its bit lengthy so i'm posting part which needed.

```
$("#RevenueReporttbl").jqGrid({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                mtype: 'GET',
                //                    url: '/AMForecast/Index/',
                height: 'auto',
               // width: 'auto',
                   width: '1150',
                gridview: true,
                datatype: "local",
                loadonce: true,
                data: search_result,
                colNames: ['ForecastId', 'CustomerId', 'Customer Name', 'UserId', 'Person', 'ProjectId', 'Project Name', 'Edit', 'Ytd'],

                colModel: [
                    { name: 'ForecastId', index: 'ForecastId', editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true, fixed: true },
                    { name: 'CustomerId', index: 'CustomerId', editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true, fixed: true },
                    { name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName', width: 130, editable: false, sortable: false, fixed: true },
                    { name: 'UserId', index: 'UserId', width: 130, editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true, fixed: true },
                    { name: 'Manager', index: 'Manager', align: 'left', width: 130, editable: false, sortable: false, fixed: true },
                    { name: 'ProjectId', index: 'ProjectId', editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true, fixed: true },
                    { name: 'ProjectName', index: 'ProjectName', editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true, fixed: true },
                    { name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', editable: false, width: 40, align: 'center', hidden: false, sortable: false, fixed: true },

                    { name: 'Ytd', index: 'Ytd', editable: false, width: 40, align: 'right', sortable: false, summaryType: 'sum', fixed: true }],
                     rowNum: 99,
                pager: '#pager',
                footerrow: true,
                userDataOnFooter: true,
                altRows: false,
                rowList: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                multipleSearch: true,
                //multiselect: true,
                multipleGroup: true,
                shrinkToFit: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                subGrid: true,
                grouping: true, //changed
                groupingView: {
                    groupField: ['CustomerType'],
                    groupSummary: [true],
                    groupColumnShow: [false],
                    groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>'],
                    groupCollapse: false,
                    groupOrder: ['asc'],
                    groupDataSorted: true
                 },
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "gridModel",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    cell: "cell",
                    id: "id",
                    subgrid: {
                        root: "gridModel",
                        repeatitems: true,
                        cell: "cell",
                        id: "id"
                    }
                }
```

So i'm using subgrid also with read only option.
Please tell how to make enter key false? I dont want to do anything when i clicked enter in edit mode.

Comment: You should post the code which you use. Inline editing can be implemented on many ways. It's important to know how you use it.

Comment: @Oleg Hi how do u do? Thanks for your JQGrid its really awesome. Add more feature too. And as u requested to paste code i've modified my post with code pls have a look over it and let me know! And if possible please give me your Skype Id or something because i realy want to be in touch with u guys.

Comment: You are welcome! Your problem is with *editing* of jqGrid. To be able to help you one have to see *how* you implemented inline editing in the grid, but the code which you posted don't contain any editing. You should post *more full code* which you use.

Answer (score 3):

Did you see the part of the docs about the `keys` setting:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

It says:

> If keys is true, then the remaining settings – successfunc, url,
>   extraparam, aftersavefunc, errorfunc and afterrestorefunc - are passed
>   as parameters to the saveRow method when the [Enter] key is pressed
>   (saveRow does not need to be defined as jqGrid calls it
>   automatically). For more information see saveRow method below.

Comment: How can we set keys=false in the colmodel?